# syntax error, unexpected 'Request' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a taxi system, and this code gives me

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Controller
{
    public Request $request;
    public array $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = [];
        $this->request = Request::capture();
        if (key_exists('user', $_SESSION)) {
            $this->user = $_SESSION['user'];
        }
        if (count($this->user) === 0 && url()->contains('panel')) {
            return redirect(url('login-form'));
        }
    }
}
```

but the system is giving me error after writing these lines of code

```
ParseError 
syntax error, unexpected 'Request' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
```

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: 7.3 is my current version

Comment: I am using php 8 and still go the error somehow....

Answer (score 18):

Yeah, typed properties were introduced in PHP 7.4.
In order to make your code snippet work, please remove properties type hints. Or update your PHP version to 7.4.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Controller
{
    public $request;
    public $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = [];
        $this->request = Request::capture();
        if (key_exists('user', $_SESSION)) {
            $this->user = $_SESSION['user'];
        }
        if (count($this->user) === 0 && url()->contains('panel')) {
            return redirect(url('login-form'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, i uppdate the system to 7.4, works now :) thanks

Answer (score 7):

Typed properties were introduced in PHP 7.4: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.typed-properties

If you are using an older PHP version, it will throw an error.